# Constructor of user-defined class not working with vector

Tags: c++, class, vector, constructor

My problem is very simple, the constructor of a class is not working with a `std::vector`.

```
class my_class
{
public:
    my_class() { std::cout << "my_class constructed\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector <my_class> v;
}
```

The program did not output anything, even though it should have outputted `my_class constructed`. I then assumed that the constructor works for each element of the `vector`, so I did this:

```
class my_class
{
public:
    my_class() { std::cout << "my_class constructed"; }
};

int main()
{
    my_class object;
    std::vector <my_class> v;
    v.push_back( object );
}
```

This code outputted:

```
my_class constructed
```

This construction occurred because of `my_class` object, not because of using `push_back()`.

How do I make the constructor work for `std::vector`?
If you require any further detail I will happily provide it.

Comment: Hint: also instrument the copy constructor.

Comment: The holy trinity, or if that's not your thing - the rule of three.

Comment: @DeiDei Or the rule of 5.

Comment: Hints: For the first one, check `v.size()`.  For the second one, try `v.emplace_back()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set an initial size of the vector, e.g. by `std::vector <my_class> v(10)`.
Then it shall actually call the constructor 10 times, because the elements of the vector get default initialized.

In your second example, when you `push_back` an object, the object is probably copied and not "constructed". If you implemented a copy constructor, you could observe this behaviour:

```
class my_class
{
public:

    my_class();
    my_class(const my_class &m) { cout << "copy constructor called" << endl; };
};
my_class::my_class()
{
    std::cout << "my_class constructed\n";
}

int main()
{
    my_class mc;

    std::vector <my_class> v;

    v.push_back(mc);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
my_class constructed
copy constructor called
```

Comment: So constructors are not called when using push_back()?

Comment: Not necessarily; objects could be copied or moved, calling then a copy or move constructor; that's why @DeiDei mentioned the rule of three.

Comment: @stance changer: see adapted code to illustrate above mentioned thing.

Answer (score 2):

In your second case, you are constructing an object and copy-constructing it in the vector. If you want to construct directly inside the vector, I recommend to use `emplace_back` without arguments:

```
v.emplace_back();
```

Comment: If you want to actually construct it directly rather than moving from a temporary, use a call to `emplace_back()`, without arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You construct an empty vector. Why would you expect your constructor to be called in that case? It won't be called until you actually put some objects in the vector.

Also, instrument your copy constructor and move constructor.